# Compatible symmetric bilinear form of differential Lie Algebra

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, lie-algebras

Consider a general $N$th order differential operator
$$A=a_0(x)+ia_1(x)\partial_x+\dots+\frac{i^N}{N!}a_N(x)\partial_x^N$$
We can represent this differential operator as a sum of derivatives of delta distributions:
$$A(x,y)=\sum_{n=0}^{N}\frac{i^n}{n!}a_n(x)\partial^n_x\delta(x-y)$$
With the understanding that the action of this distribution on a test function $f(x)$ is
$$Af=\int dy A(x,y)f(y).$$
The delta derivatives can be thought of as generators of a Lie Algebra, whose commutator between differential operators $A$ and $B$ of order less than or equal to $N$ gives a new differential operator $C$ with order less than or equal to $N$.
$$[A,B]=C$$
$$C(x,y)=\sum_{n=0}^N\frac{i^n}{n!}\Bigg(\sum_{k=0}^N\sum_{m=0}^n\frac{i^k}{k!} {n \choose m }\Big(a_{k+m}\partial^k b_{n-m}-b_{k+m}\partial^k a_{n-m}\Big) \Bigg)\partial_x^n\delta(x-y)$$

If the subscript $k+m$ becomes greater than $N$, the resulting coefficient $a_{k+m}=0$. This commutator is defined the standard way:

$$[A,B](x,y)=\int dz \big(A(x,z)B(z,y)-B(x,z)A(z,y)\big).$$

This Lie Algebra has structure constants $C^{n}_{\;\; ij}$, with $n,i,j=0,\dots N$ such that

$$C^{n}_{\;\; ij}a_i(x)b_j(x)=\sum_{k=0}^N\sum_{m=0}^n\frac{i^k}{k!} {n \choose m }\Big(a_{k+m}\partial^k b_{n-m}-b_{k+m}\partial^k a_{n-m}\Big).$$

My question is, does there exist a compatible symmetric bilinear form $g_{ij}$, which is invariant under the adjoint representation defined by the above structure constants? I'd also like to see an example of a Lie Algebra which does not admit such a bilinear form.

Comment: It's possible I've misunderstood your question but there is always an invariant symmetric bilinear form on any Lie algebra: The Killing form. Of course if the lie algebra is not semisimple this is a degenerate form though I'm not sure whether you can find another nondegenerate form in general. Certainly for an abelian Lie algebra, invariant becomes a vacuous condition so any nondegenerate symmetric bilinear form will do.

Comment: @Callum Thank you for your comment. At the time of writing this question the Killing form slipped my mind. I actually tried to calculate the Killing form and it was not very well defined (it ended up being a product of two delta functions). There may be a way of regulating it but I am not sure.